# Load centralized HTML and CSS files

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess, vps

I am building sites on a single server and wish to use some centralized HTML and CSS files across all sites, so that I can make changes to a single HTML or CSS that will affect multiple sites.

The centralized files sit in the /home folder on my server (above the domain folders)

Example folder structure:

```
/home
/home/templates
/home/templates/template1.html
/home/templates/css/style.css
```

example domain (mydomain.com):

```
/home/mydomain/public_html/index.php
```

When I call the template1.html file from the index.php from the mydomain folder, it loads the html file ok, but because the template1.html references css/style.css as the style file, it tries to load the file as if it is mydomain.com/css/style.css rather than from the /home/templates folder.

I understand that it is doing exactly what it should be doing, but is there a way that I could use a htaccess rule or something to redirect it back to the /home/templates folder?  Or is there a way I could reference the location of the CSS file correctly from the html file?

Comment: This could help to set absolute paths that will work from any template : http://php.net/manual/fr/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a slightly different approach to this to get it working.

I added a line to my htaccess to redirect style.css to style.php:

```
RewriteRule ^style\.css$ style.php [L]
```

The style.php then grabs the name of the template from a variable in a config PHP file - "template3.html" and converts it to "template3.css" (using str_replace).

It then includes the "/home/thin/templates/template3.css" file.

The style.php also contains the following line to force the content to be seen as CSS:

```
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 1):

Have this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^((?:css|js|images)/.+)$ /home/templates/$1 [L,NC]
```